# check the unicity of a table field postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

given certain circumstances (big dataset stored in a table), I need to check the unicity of a field for a Postgres table.

for simplification purposes let's say I have the following table:

```
id   |    name
--------------
1    |  david
2    |  catrine
3    |  hmida
```

and I want to check for the unicity of the field name; the result would be true
so far I managed to use a similar code to the following:

```
select name, count(*)
from test
group by name
having count(*) > 1
```

put in mind that I have a big dataset, so I prefer this to be handled by the RDBMS rather than fetching the data by an adapter (e.g. psycopg2).
so again I need to optimize as much as possible. any nerdy idea ?

Comment: Does you code not work (it looks like it should)? What is the question?

Comment: the query takes 2min for a 10 million row dataset, I need something much faster.

Comment: with your query data is processed on DB side - not psycopg2

Comment: @VaoTsun yes my data is processed on DB side not psycopg2

Comment: Can you show the EXPLAIN? If it's about performance, there may be some improvements you can make...

Comment: @NevilleKuyt  my goal is to see if I am missing a technical optimization because I'm checking the unicity of multiple fields. so generally speaking I'm looking for the most optimal general solution to such a problem.
the 'explain' optimization technique comes after the solution don't you think, I'm no expert in DB systems. best regards

Comment: Do you have an index on the `name` column? That might speed up the query. If you want to prevent duplicates in that column in general, you should cleanup the data and then create a `unique` index on that to prevent duplicates being inserted in the future.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's beside the point, since I'm checking the unicity of multiple fields in the table, so let's say i create an index for each field i'm checking, the insertion time will be very terrible, so in my modest point of view the index solution should not be abused, any way I appreciate your pricless advice best regards.

Comment: "*the insertion time will be very terrible*" is a wrong assumption - especially the "terrible" part. Yes, an index does slow down insert - but definitely **not** in a "terrible" way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would be probably faster, but not too reliable solution:

```
t=# create table t (i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into t select generate_series(1,9,1);
INSERT 0 9
t=# insert into t select generate_series(1,999999,1);
INSERT 0 999999
t=# insert into t select generate_series(1,9999999,1);
INSERT 0 9999999
```

now your query:

```
t=# select i,count(*) from t group by i having count(*) > 1 order by 2 desc,1 limit 1;
 i | count
---+-------
 1 |     3
(1 row)

Time: 7538.476 ms
```

now checking from statistics:

```
t=# analyze t;
ANALYZE
Time: 1079.465 ms
    t=# with fr as (select most_common_vals::text::text[] from pg_stats where tablename = 't' and attname='i')
    select count(1),i from t join fr on true where i::text = any(most_common_vals) group by i;
     count |   i
    -------+--------
         2 |  94933
         2 | 196651
         2 | 242894
         2 | 313829
         2 | 501027
         2 | 757714
         2 | 778442
         2 | 896602
         2 | 929918
         2 | 979650
         2 | 999259
    (11 rows)

    Time: 3584.582 ms
```

and lastly just checking if not uniq exist with just one of most frequent values:

```
t=# select count(1),i from t where i::text = (select (most_common_vals::text::text[])[1] from pg_stats where tablename = 't' and attname='i') group by i;
 count |  i
-------+------
     2 | 1540
(1 row)

Time: 1871.907 ms
```

**update**

`pg_stats` data is modifyed after statistics are gathered on the table. Thus you have a chance of having not fresh aggregated stats on data distribution. In my sample for instance:

```
t=# delete from t where i = 1540;
DELETE 2
Time: 941.684 ms
t=# select count(1),i from t where i::text = (select (most_common_vals::text::text[])[1] from pg_stats where tablename = 't' and attname='i') group by i;
 count | i
-------+---
(0 rows)

Time: 1876.136 ms
t=# analyze t;
ANALYZE
Time: 77.108 ms
t=# select count(1),i from t where i::text = (select (most_common_vals::text::text[])[1] from pg_stats where tablename = 't' and attname='i') group by i;
 count |   i
-------+-------
     2 | 41377
(1 row)

Time: 1878.260 ms
```

of course if you rely on more then just one most frequent value, the failure chances are reduced, but again - such method depends on statistics "freshness".

Comment: can you elaborate on why you described your solution with 'not reliable', in what case this is not reliable. thanks a lot.